# Are there cases in C++ where the auto keyword can't be replaced by an explicit type?

Tags: c++, c++20, variable-types

I came across the following code:

```
auto x = new int[10][10];
```

Which compiles and runs correctly but I can't figure out what would be the type for defining `x` separately from the assignment.

When debugging the type shown is `int(*)[10]` for `x` but `int (*) x[10];` (or any other combination I tried) is illegal.

So are there cases where `auto` can't be replaced by an explicit type...? (and is this such a case?)

Comment: Just try `x = 54;` and you'll get an error that will tell you the type.

Comment: `auto lambda = [](){};` is a case where `auto` cannot be replaced by an explicit type (at least, not without changing the semantics), because the type doesn't have a name. So yes, there are such cases; but your example ain't one of them.

Comment: The correct syntax is `int (*x)[10]`

Comment: `class Outer { class Inner {}; public: Inner getInner() { return {}; } }; void unrelated() { auto x = Outer{}.getInner(); }` is another instance where you can't replace `auto` with the type name

Comment: Another example where you must use `auto` is when creating a variable of **unscoped unnamed enum** type as given in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237458/12002570). [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EM654dxoz)

Comment: @andreee: I would say as title doesn't fully matching the description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `x` is `int (*)[10]`. There are different ways of figuring this out. The simplest is to just try assigning `5` to `x` and noticing what the error says:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[10]' [-fpermissive]
   13 |     x = 4;
      |         ^
      |         |
      |         int
```

Or just use `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), int(*)[10]>::value);
```

This means that if you want to explicitly create `x`(without using `auto`) then you can do it as:

```
int (*x)[10] = new int[10][10];
```

---

> Are there cases in C++ where the auto keyword can't be replaced by an explicit type?

Now coming to the title, one example where `auto` cannot be directly replaced by explicitly writing a type is when dealing with **unscoped unnamed enum** as shown below: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EM654dxoz)

```
enum
{
    a,b,c
}obj;

int main()
{
//--vvvv----------->must use auto or decltype(obj)
    auto  obj2 = obj;
}
```

Similarly, when dealing with **unnamed class**. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PKo937qbq).

Comment: The question already mentions that debugging says the type is `int(*)[10]`. The question is what the syntax would be for creating a variable of type `int(*)[10]`, instead of using `auto` which deduces to that type.

Comment: @NathanPierson I've added that at the end of my answer. In particular, that we can do it using `int (*x)[10] = new int[10][10];`. Once we know the problem the solution(in this case) is *trivial* atleast to me(but not maybe to the OP and beginners), so to be more explicit I've added that if OP don't want to use `auto` then they can write `int (*x)[10] = new int[10][10];`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a case in which you have to *necessarily* use `auto`.

But answering the question in the title, I can think of 3 cases where you need `auto`.

1. As @IgorTandetnik said in a comment, lambas. `auto f = [](){...};`.
2. returning of a local class, which has its uses.

```
auto f() {  // auto needed here
  struct A{
    double x;
    double y;
  };

  return A{...};
};
...
auto result = f();  // auto needed here
```

3. Unnamed class (or enums)

```
struct {
...
} pi;

auto pi2 = pi;
```

---

Case 2 is sometimes used to define an ad-hoc type.

For example, what type should a `minmax(std::vector<double> const&)` return?

You could return some standard type `std::pair<double, double>`, but why would `.first` and `.second` indicate the two results?

With this instead, the labels are more clear and you don't have class dissociated with the specific purpose.

```
auto minmax(std::vector<double>& v) {
   struct result_t{
      double min;
      double max;
   }
   ...
   return result_t{m, M};
}
...

auto result = minmax(v);
... use result.min and result.max ...
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give an example use-case for (2)?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of types, using typedef might help usage:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using CArray = T[N];
```

and then

```
CArray<int, 10>* x = new CArray<int, 10>[10];
```

Else, the syntax is quite *"ugly"*:

```
int (*x)[10] = new int[10][10];
```